# How to solve $\int_{0}^{\beta}\frac{e^{ax-\frac{b}{x}}}{\alpha-x}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I'm facing with this integral in my thesis. I have 'dejavu' that I have seen this kind of integral before but I can't remember exactly. Can anyone guide me to solve this one?

$$\int_0^\beta \frac{e^{ax-\frac{b}{x}}}{\alpha-x} \, dx$$

Comment: It's not an elementary antiderivative.  Neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha find a closed form.  I expect there is none.

Comment: I think it can be represented as exponential integrals :(

Comment: I do not think it could be. Even $\int e^{ax-\frac bx}\,dx$ is  already a problem.

Comment: @ÂnVương Why do you think that?

Comment: Idk just a feeling .__. Anyway, it's okay now, my prof. says let just approximate this since this integral is tightly bounded in the region $(0,\beta)$. Thanks guys

Comment: Given the fact that even the simple case $~-a=b=1,~\alpha=\dfrac1\beta=0~$ does not possess a closed form in terms of elementary functions, but rather only in terms of the [Bessel K function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), the only feasible approaches seem to be numerical rather than analytical.